# Pycuda:: there is a way to pass a float3 * parameter to a kernel from a numpy array with shape=(N,3)?

Tags: python, pycuda

Is it possible to use a numpy array of `shape (10, 3)` like an array of 10 `float3` inside a pycuda kernel?

I'm trying to solve the problem of nearest point, with an array on point `array_point` of `shape (10,3)` where 10 are the point locations, for example `array_point[0]` is `[x,y,z]`.

To solve this I really want to send to the kernel an float3* parameter, but I'm not sure how to do it.

```py
# for simplicity I will use a 4 point case with all handwritten directly
# only mockup script, not really working... actually is the question

import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
from pycuda import gpuarray, tools

import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[7,8,9], [10,11,12]], dtype=np.float32)
print(data.shape)
data_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(data)

// out must be like out_gpu[0] -> 1 means point 0 nearest point is point 1 ... I Hope be clear with the main idea

out_gpu = gpuarray.empty(4, np.int32)


mod = SourceModule("""
  __device__ float distance_not_sqrt(float3 p1, float3 p2)
  {
     return (p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p2.y) * (p1.y - p2.y) + (p1.z - p2.z) * (p1.z - p2.z) ;
  }

  __global__ void find_closest(float3 *a, int*out)
  {
    int idx = threadIdx.x;
    int it;
    int it_min = -1;
    float dist_min = 1000.0; // more large than any real distance point
    for(it=0; it < 4; it++){
        if(it==idx)continue
        float dist = distance_not_sqrt(a[id], a[it])
        if(dist < dist_min){
            dist_min = dist;
            it_min = it;
        }
    }
    out[idx] = it_min;
  }
  """)

func = mod.get_function("find_closest")
func(data_gpu, out_gpu, block=(4,1,1))
print(out_gpu.get())
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing 10 x 3 numpy arrays will automatically work for float3 arrays, but you will need to make sure your contiguous dimension (dimension where elements are next to each other) is the one with the 3 in it. For example, a numpy array like so:

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],dtype=np.float32,order='C')
```

is the same as 4 `float3` values of `(1,2,3)`, you can check this using `np.ravel(order='K')`

```
x.ravel(order='K')
array([1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3.], dtype=float32)
```

but if instead use fortran order (denoted with 'F', where 'C' is C order), the result won't be what we expect if we wanted 4 `(1,2,3)` `float3s`.

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],dtype=np.float32,order='F')
```

and the result:

```
x.ravel(order='K')
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3.], dtype=float32)
```

This is because our contiguous dimension is the *first one* in fortran order (ie in `x.shape == (4,3)`, the first dimension, 4, is our contiguous dimension in fortran order, and the last dimension is our contiguous dimension in C order)

Your example should work minus some bugs (like `id` being used but never declared, assume you mean `idx`?)